# Minimum speed of mass so the mass on top can slide off

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

I was given this question and I want to ask few things about it:

Given big mass M, we place small mass m (initial velocity relative to ground = 0) in the middle of M, what minimal initial velocity V should we give to M so the small mass can slide and fall of the big mass? There is friction between m and M, the static and kinetic friction coefficient is μ.

I figured out that the best way is to use conservation of energy, ΔE = W(NC) , but I cant find the final kinetic energy of the system. Also I calculated the center of mass velocity to be M*V/(M + m), is this accurate?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Whether the smaller block falls or not depends on  acceleration and not on velocity .The two block system  may reach any velocity given sufficient time .

Comment: Do "big" and "small" mean we should neglect the acceleration of M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is much easier to solve from the frame of reference of M block.Here , as time progresses the relative velocity of m with respect to M decreases due to friction until it becomes zero and m comes at rest with respect to M.At the minimum velocity required for block to fall off , the relative velocity of m becomes zero exactly at the point A so that upon slightly increasing imparted velocity(v) from this minimum value the block m falls off.Now we know that ,

initial relative velocity of m (u)=$v_{min}$

Final relative velocity of m =0

Displacement of m from initial position at the midpoint  to point A = $\frac L2$

acceleration = - $\mu$g - $\frac {\mu mg}M$ (Sum total of acceleration due to friction as well as pseudo force)

Using Third Equation of Motion,$$v^2 = u^2 + 2aS$$$$0 = v_{min}^2 - 2(\mu g + \frac {\mu mg}M )\frac L2$$$$v_{min}^2 =(\mu g + \frac {\mu mg}M)L$$$$v_{min} = \sqrt{(\mu g + \frac {\mu mg}M)L}$$

which is my answer.
[image]

Comment: Be sure to check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy is not a good approach in a problem involving friction, since energy is *not* conserved when friction is involved. However, conservation of momentum still holds (as long as there is no friction between the larger block and the ground) so that is a better starting point.

Initially the momentum of the system of two blocks is $MV$. If we assume the smaller block does not fall off the larger block then they both eventually reach a final steady state speed $U$ and conservation of momentum tells us that

$MV = (M+m)U
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow U = \frac M {M+m} V$

Note that $U<V$, because while the friction between the blocks speeds up the smaller block, it also slows down the larger block. Also note that energy is not conserved, since

$\displaystyle \frac 1 2 (M+m)U^2 = \frac 1 2 MVU < \frac 1 2 MV^2$

The force of friction on the smaller block is $\mu mg$, so its acceleration is $\mu g$. If the smaller block can reach a speed $U$ at constant acceleration $\mu g$ *before* it reaches the left-hand end of the larger block then it will stay on the larger block.

Now the problem can be re-stated as follows: How long does it take the smaller block at constant acceleration $\mu g$ to reach the steady state speed $U$ ? At this time, where is the smaller block and where is the left-hand end of the larger block ?